# hover on svg circle show tooltip for each element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, tooltip

I'm designing a website for myself. I have created three svg circle when I hover or mouseenter on each svg circle should show different tooltip images. I've tried but it's not working. I'm using materialcss framework when I use push class to push all the three colors to the right side of the screen leaving some margin.

```js
            
            
            $('svg[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
            animated: 'fade',
            placement: 'bottom',
            html: true
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
                <div class="priority-order">
                <div class="col l1 m1 s1 push-l9">
              <svg height="100" width="100" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<img src='images/4%20projects%202.jpg' style='height:100px;width:100px' />">
              <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="10" stroke-width="3" fill="#f0584f" />
              </svg>
                </div>
                
              <div class="col l1 m1 s1 push-l9"> 
              <svg height="100" width="100">
              <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="10" stroke-width="3" fill="#3166ff" />
              </svg>
                    </div>    
                
              <div class="col l1 m1 s1 push-l9">
              <svg height="100" width="100">
              <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="10" stroke-width="3" fill="#5fb336" />
              </svg>
                    </div>
                    
            </div>
            </div>
```

[image: I've designed this page]

This is the present homescreen

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created custom tooltip of my own by CSS. This research took me one day to complete the task.

```css
.priority-order svg{
    float: right;
    margin-left: -25px;
}

/*tooltips green color dot*/

a.tooltips {
  position: relative;
  right: 5px;
  float: right;
}

a.tooltips span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #5FB336;
  height: 29px;
  line-height: 29px;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
a.tooltips span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
  width: 0; height: 0;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #5FB336;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
}
a:hover.tooltips span {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 50px;
  left: 30%;
  margin-left: -57px;
  z-index: 999;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*tooltips1 blue color dot*/

a.tooltips1 {
  position: relative;
  right: 5px;
  float: right;
}

a.tooltips1 span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #3166ff;
  height: 29px;
  line-height: 29px;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
a.tooltips1 span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
  width: 0; height: 0;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #3166ff;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
}
a:hover.tooltips1 span {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 50px;
  left: 30%;
  margin-left: -57px;
  z-index: 999;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*tooltips1 red color dot*/

a.tooltips2 {
  position: relative;
  right: 5px;
  float: right;
}

a.tooltips2 span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #f0584f;
  height: 29px;
  line-height: 29px;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
a.tooltips2 span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
  width: 0; height: 0;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #f0584f;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
}
a:hover.tooltips2 span {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 50px;
  left: 30%;
  margin-left: -57px;
  z-index: 999;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
                <div class="priority-order">
                    
                      <div class="">
<a class="right tooltips" href="#"><svg height="40" width="100" class="">
              <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="10" stroke-width="3" fill="#5fb336" />
                <span>Clear</span>
    </svg></a>
                    </div>  
                    
                     <div class="">
<a class="right tooltips1" href="#"><svg height="40" width="100" class="">
              <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="10" stroke-width="3" fill="#3166ff" />
                <span>Issue</span>
    </svg></a>   
                    </div>
                
            
                <div class="">
<a class="right tooltips2" href="#"><svg height="40" width="100" class="">
              <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="10" stroke-width="3" fill="#f0584f" />
                <span>Alert</span>
    </svg></a>   
                    </div>
                
            </div>
            </div>
```